# Count nodes based on two or more attribute values

Tags: xpath

I need to count how many times a particular node occurs in a document based on the values of two if its attributes.  So, given the following small sample of XML:

```
 <p:entry timestamp="2012-11-15T17:53:34.642-05:00" ticks="89709622449012" system="OSD" component="OSD5" marker=".\Launcher.cpp:1741" severity="Info" type="Driver" subtype="Start" tags="" sensitivity="false">
```

This can occur one or more times in the document with different attribute sets.  I need to count how many show up with type="Driver" AND subtype="Start".  I am able to count how many just have type="Driver" using:

```
 count(//p:entry[@type="Driver"])
```

but haven't been able to combine them.  This didn't work:

```
 count(//p:entry[@type="Driver" and @subtype="Start"])
```

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried `//p:entry[@type="Driver"][@subtype="Start"]`

Comment: That worked!!  I could have swore I tried that too.  Please repost as an answer and I'll chose it.  Thanks!

Comment: By right, the code that you say don't work should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? The XPath expression you are using is correct and if its evaluation doesn't produce the correct result, this may mean that the XPath implementation you are using has bugs.

Comment: Dimitre, I think the XPath app I was using was the issue.  It was called XPathBuilder.  I've since switch to Notepad++ with the XPatherizerNPP plugin which seems to work much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the OP. Specify 2 predicates in succession instead of using operator `and` result in the same effect:

```
count(//p:entry[@type="Driver"][@subtype="Start"])
```

By right, the original code `count(//p:entry[@type="Driver" and @subtype="Start"])` should work, as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: This is really weird.  I went back and tried it with 'and' as well and both worked.  I was getting errors before so not sure what is different now. Anyway, thanks for looking into it.